# Usinr DHT11 sensor on jetson nano using python

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to connect and use a DHT11 Temp sensor on a jeston nano.
I am using C_DHT.c lib

Below is the kind of error msg I get:

```
gpioSetDirection: Unknown error 517
gpioSetValue: Operation not permitted
gpioSetValue: Operation not permitted
gpioSetDirection: Unknown error 517
gpioSetDirection: Unknown error 517
gpioSetValue: Operation not permitted
TG(-39909.0, -39909.0, 0)
```

Build and install C_DHT.c done successfully with sudo.

Comment: You'll also need to run your program as root, most likely.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it's not enough, I am using the python console launched by "sudo python", I guess it's ok, correct ?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/NVIDIA/jetson-gpio#setting-user-permissions then.

Comment: Ok great ! So my jetsonGPIO install is no complete apparently ! I will try this and get you. Thanks

Comment: Still not but I think I have trouble regarding what permissions are set for python and for python3

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the permission issues, it was due to wrong pin number setup. But I am still always getting (-39909.0, -39909.0, 0) as response. so no real measure. If anybody could help with correct connections, info are welcome. Thanks.

I am using a 3 pin DHT11,
left pin connected to 3.3v
center pin to pin 37 of the jetson nano for the data
right pin to grn through a 10k resistor.

Comment: I ditched this type of sensor, I switched to an I2C sensor and now have a working solution.